# display quasi-real-time data to user with php/ajax

Tags: php, compilation

I currently have a class `Status`, and I call it throughout my code as I preform various tasks, for example - when I upload an image, I call `$statusHandler = new Status(121)`, when I resize it, I call `$statusHandler = new Status(122)`.
Every statusID corresponds to a certain text stored in the database.
Class `status` retrieves the text, and stores in `$_SESSION`.
I have another file, `getstatus.php`, that returns the current status. 
My idea was to call `getstatus.php` every 500 miliseconds with ajax (via jquery), and append the text to the webpage.
This way the user gets (almost) real-time data about what calculations are going on in the background.

The problem is that I only seem to be getting the last status.
I thought that it just was a result of things happening too quickly, so I ran `sleep` after calling `new Status`. This delayed the entire output of the page, meaning PHP didn't output *any* text until it completed running through the code.
Does PHP echo data only after it finishes running through all the code, or does it do it real-time, line-by-line?
If so, can anyone offer any workarounds so that I can achieve what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The default session implementation (flat file) sets a file lock on the session-file when session_start() is called. This lock is not released until the session mechanism shuts down, i.e. when the script has ended or [session_write_close()](http://php.net/session_write_close) is executed. Another request/thread that wants to access the same session has to wait until this lock has been released.

Comment: if i write session_write_close(), i won't be able to start it again, since headers have already been sent! any help with this?